# Can I leave out the rel attribute from a link element in html?

Tags: html, validation, hyperlink, html4

I am doing w3c validation of my HTML code. And I seem to have stumbled across persistent errors in my quest. Basically Every page that imports the link element has a problem with the using the rel attribute. The validator throws me an error saying the link attribute is at fault.

> Line 8, column 54: document type does not allow element "LINK" here

I have included the link in the `<head>` section of my document.
When I remove `rel="stylesheet"` then the validator will accept this.

As far as I understand the rel is use for identifying the relationship between documents. as per the  [W3C HTML 4.01 Transitional spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really get your problem.

> Can I leave out the rel attribute from a link element in html?

Short answer, sure! You *can* use the `rel` attribute, but you don't have to!

This is pretty much all you need to add a valid link to your html-file.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">I link to Google</a>
```